# Using R to reshape and plot linux dstat CSV file

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2

I'm trying to use `reshape2` to format this 90-observation [dstat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dstat) data so that I can plot it in a reasonable manner, but I cannot figure out how to translate all the `foo.5` columns into a something I can easily plot with ggplot2.

```
> library(RCurl)
> x <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hamiltont/27d9f93ad53d8978bccd/raw/ec6118805b9ab8606a303dc81450a6f760864cf9/dstat.csv")
> dstat = read.csv(file="stats", skip=6, header=TRUE)
> names(dstat)
  [1] "usr"    "sys"    "idl"    "wai"    "hiq"   
  [6] "siq"    "usr.1"  "sys.1"  "idl.1"  "wai.1" 
 [11] "hiq.1"  "siq.1"  "usr.2"  "sys.2"  "idl.2" 
 [16] "wai.2"  "hiq.2"  "siq.2"  "usr.3"  "sys.3" 
 [21] "idl.3"  "wai.3"  "hiq.3"  "siq.3"  "usr.4" 
 [26] "sys.4"  "idl.4"  "wai.4"  "hiq.4"  "siq.4" 
 [31] "usr.5"  "sys.5"  "idl.5"  "wai.5"  "hiq.5" 
 [36] "siq.5"  "usr.6"  "sys.6"  "idl.6"  "wai.6" 
 [41] "hiq.6"  "siq.6"  "usr.7"  "sys.7"  "idl.7" 
 [46] "wai.7"  "hiq.7"  "siq.7"  "usr.8"  "sys.8" 
 [51] "idl.8"  "wai.8"  "hiq.8"  "siq.8"  "usr.9" 
 [56] "sys.9"  "idl.9"  "wai.9"  "hiq.9"  "siq.9" 
 [61] "usr.10" "sys.10" "idl.10" "wai.10" "hiq.10"
 [66] "siq.10" "usr.11" "sys.11" "idl.11" "wai.11"
 [71] "hiq.11" "siq.11" "usr.12" "sys.12" "idl.12"
 [76] "wai.12" "hiq.12" "siq.12" "usr.13" "sys.13"
 [81] "idl.13" "wai.13" "hiq.13" "siq.13" "usr.14"
 [86] "sys.14" "idl.14" "wai.14" "hiq.14" "siq.14"
 [91] "usr.15" "sys.15" "idl.15" "wai.15" "hiq.15"
 [96] "siq.15" "usr.16" "sys.16" "idl.16" "wai.16"
[101] "hiq.16" "siq.16" "usr.17" "sys.17" "idl.17"
[106] "wai.17" "hiq.17" "siq.17" "usr.18" "sys.18"
[111] "idl.18" "wai.18" "hiq.18" "siq.18" "usr.19"
[116] "sys.19" "idl.19" "wai.19" "hiq.19" "siq.19"
[121] "usr.20" "sys.20" "idl.20" "wai.20" "hiq.20"
[126] "siq.20" "usr.21" "sys.21" "idl.21" "wai.21"
[131] "hiq.21" "siq.21" "usr.22" "sys.22" "idl.22"
[136] "wai.22" "hiq.22" "siq.22" "usr.23" "sys.23"
[141] "idl.23" "wai.23" "hiq.23" "siq.23" "read"  
[146] "writ"   "recv"   "send"   "recv.1" "send.1"
[151] "recv.2" "send.2" "in."    "out"    "int"   
[156] "csw"    "X20"    "X21"    "X23"    "X76"   
[161] "X77"    "X78"    "X79"    "X80"    "X81"   
[166] "X82"    "X83"    "X1m"    "X5m"    "X15m"  
[171] "used"   "buff"   "cach"   "free"   "run"   
[176] "blk"    "new"    "read.1" "writ.1" "used.1"
[181] "free.1" "epoch"  "X.aio"  "files"  "inodes"
[186] "msg"    "sem"    "shm"    "pos"    "lck"   
[191] "rea"    "wri"    "raw"    "tot"    "tcp"   
[196] "udp"    "raw.1"  "frg"    "lis"    "act"   
[201] "syn"    "tim"    "clo"    "raw.2"  "tot.1" 
[206] "tcp.1"  "udp.1"  "raw.3"  "frg.1"  "lis.1" 
[211] "act.1"  "syn.1"  "tim.1"  "clo.1"  "lis.2" 
[216] "act.2"  "dgm"    "str"    "lis.3"  "act.3" 
[221] "majpf"  "minpf"  "alloc"  "free.2" "util"  
[226] "call"   "retr"   "refr"   "call.1" "erca"  
[231] "erau"   "ercl"   "xdrc"
```

For my first plot I'd just love to show all the `usr.*` columns as different colored lines, which I would do using something like this:

```
ggplot(dstat, aes(x=observation, y=usr, color=usr_type) +
  geom_line()
```

If I could convince my data frame to look like this:

```
observation | usr_type | value
1             usr        22
1             usr.1      32
1             usr.2      12
<snip>
2             usr        21
2             usr.1      20
2             usr.2      20
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but I would suggest using `Stacked` from my "splitstackshape" package.

The basic approach would be something like this:

```
library(splitstackshape) ## Also loads "data.table"
DT <- as.data.table(dstat, keep.rownames = TRUE)
Stacked(DT, id.vars = "rn", var.stubs = "usr", 
        sep = "var.stubs", keep.all = FALSE)
#       rn .time_1   usr
#    1:  1         0.027
#    2:  1      .1 8.068
#    3:  1     .10 0.022
#    4:  1     .11 3.276
#    5:  1     .12 0.003
#   ---                 
# 2060:  9      .5 0.000
# 2061:  9      .6 0.000
# 2062:  9      .7 0.000
# 2063:  9      .8 0.000
# 2064:  9      .9 0.000
```

However, you can also do more interesting things, like "stack" multiple groups of columns. For instance, to create a `list` with the "stacked" versions of "usr", "sys", and "wai" variables, you could do:

```
varsOfInterest <- c("usr", "sys", "wai")
Stacked(DT, id.vars = "rn", var.stubs = varsOfInterest, 
        sep = "var.stubs", keep.all = FALSE)
# $usr
#       rn .time_1   usr
#    1:  1         0.027
#    2:  1      .1 8.068
#    3:  1     .10 0.022
#    4:  1     .11 3.276
#    5:  1     .12 0.003
#   ---                 
# 2060:  9      .5 0.000
# 2061:  9      .6 0.000
# 2062:  9      .7 0.000
# 2063:  9      .8 0.000
# 2064:  9      .9 0.000
# 
# $sys
#       rn .time_1   sys
#    1:  1         0.010
#    2:  1      .1 5.000
#    3:  1     .10 0.009
#    4:  1     .11 2.559
#    5:  1     .12 0.001
#   ---                 
# 2060:  9      .5 2.000
# 2061:  9      .6 0.000
# 2062:  9      .7 0.000
# 2063:  9      .8 0.000
# 2064:  9      .9 0.000
# 
# $wai
#       rn .time_1   wai
#    1:  1         0.027
#    2:  1      .1 0.036
#    3:  1     .10 0.003
#    4:  1     .11 0.038
#    5:  1     .12 0.003
#   ---                 
# 2060:  9      .5 0.000
# 2061:  9      .6 0.000
# 2062:  9      .7 0.000
# 2063:  9      .8 0.000
# 2064:  9      .9 0.000
```

The `sep = "var.stubs"` argument basically says that there is no real separator in the column names. This isn't *exactly* true for your dataset, but it saves you from having to rename the first column of each set to something like "usr.0". If the data were already in that form, then you would be able to use `.` as the value for `sep`.

Comment: This looks perfect, but I can't get it to work like you show on my data. When using `sep="var.stubs"` it returns an error `Error in names(x) <- c(".var", paste(".time", 1:(length(x) - 1), sep = "_")) : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]`, and when I added a column `usr.0` and used `sep="."` it completed without errors but didn't extract the data as shown above (it returned `      rn .time_1 .time_2 .time_3 .time_4 .time_5   usr
   1:  1                                         0.425
   2:  1                                         2.484`. Any idea why?

Comment: @Hamy, I thought the file you linked to *was* your data. What version of "splitstackshape" and "data.table" are you using? What OS?

Comment: It is, that's why I was confused too :-P `splitstackshape version 1.2.0`, `data.table version 1.9.2`, and `OS X 10.9.5`

Comment: @Hamy, please update both "splitstackshape" and "data.table". The most recent "splitstackshape" on CRAN is 1.4.2, and "data.table" is 1.9.4, I believe.

Comment: That fixed it. I had to compile both from source (e.g. `install.packages("splitstackshape", type="source")`) because there were no binaries available. RStudio seems to default to binaries for package updates so I wasn't getting the new stuff (it did warn me with this, but I missed the message `There is a binary version available (and will be installed) but the source version
  is later:`

Comment: @Hamy, OK cool. There were some pretty big changes between 1.2 and 1.4 for "splitstackshape", so I hope you also find it a worthwhile update :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
library(reshape2)   
dstat$obs<-1:nrow(dstat)
u<-names(dstat)[grep("usr", names(dstat))]
dstat1<-dstat[,c("obs",u)]
dstat2<-melt(dstat1, id=c("obs"))
dstat2<-dstat2[order(dstat2$obs),]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dstat -tcmn --output node.csv  #output dstat

mail -a node.csv -s "Backup File" tank.sui@xxx.com < /dev/null  #send as attachment
```

**RStudio & plotly**

```
library(plotly)
ds = read.table("C:\\Users\\tank.sui\\Desktop\\node.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",",skip=6)
p <- plot_ly(x=strptime(date.time,"%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),y=idl,name="Test",data=ds)
p
```

**Screenshot below is a statictics on cpu idle.**
[image: cpu idl statistics]